Automate the use of approve() without having to do it manually
I'm taking my first steps on Solidity. I would like the user to be able to use their funds by calling the dapp functions, but without having to use the approve() function manually on the token contracts. Is there any way to do this? I would like somehow the commented statements to be called from msg.sender and not from the contract where the function is defined.
function addLiquidity(
    uint256 _amountFireToken,
    uint256 _amountWaterToken
) public onlyRegistered returns (uint256 sharesToReturn) {
    // Make sure the user has enough FireCoin tokens.
    require(
        fireCoin.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _amountFireToken,
        "Insufficient FireCoin balance!"
    );
    // Make sure the user has enough WaterCoin tokens.
    require(
        waterCoin.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _amountWaterToken,
        "Insufficient WaterCoin balance!"
    );
    // ???? fireCoin.transfer(address(this), _amountFireToken);
    // ???? waterCoin.transfer(address(this), _amountFireToken);
    sharesToReturn = myAmm.addLiquidity(_amountFireToken, _amountWaterToken);
} // end function


In order to approve a contract to spend tokens on behalf of the user, the user must call the approve function of the corresponding token contract by passing in the contract address as spender and the number of tokens (in the corresponding token's decimal representation) as amount so as to approve the allowance of spending the specified amount of tokens on behalf of the owner (i.e., the user holding the tokens).
If you try to achieve the same from within the underlying contract, then it's basically approving the contract to spend tokens on behalf of the contract (not on behalf of the user), because while calling the approve function of the token contract from within the contract, the msg.sender in the approve function call would always be the address of the contract, not the address of the user.
So, the easy and direct way to achieve that functionality in the dApp would be to ask the user to approve only if there is insufficient allowance. Basically a transaction (or the contract's function call) which requires a specific allowance of a token for the contract, then the MetaMask should pop-up for the approve transaction first, and after the successful approval, it should wait for a few seconds (that can be achieved using sleep), then the MetaMask should pop-up again for the actual transaction corresponding to the contract's function call.
Another way would be to use the ERC20Permit extension on top of the ERC20 token contract (if you're the one deploying the token contract), so as to have the user signed the sufficient approval at the time of onboarding, and utilise the same later to call the approve function on behalf of the user, when allowance is needed.
Ideally, you should follow the former way if you've just started building.
